# how to have advanced list item in listview

Tags: android, listview

I want to get my list items to look like this -

[image]

I have a list of items that have % values associated with them. This layout looks really attractive. Can anyone tell me how can this be done?

Here's the code I have tried -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:background="#98F5FF"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >
  </LinearLayout>

  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="horizontal"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:id="@+id/text1"
  android:textSize="25dip"
  android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
  android:text="This is text1"/> 
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a relative layout with a linear layout for the green background and another layout for placing all your items so that the background doesn't cover them. Change the width of your background linear layout according to percents.
This is schematically what your xml will look like:

```
<RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout /> // for background

    <LinearLayout android:background="@android:color/transparent">
        //all other elements in your view go here
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Set the height of linear layout by `myLinearLayout.getLayoutParams().height = x;`

Comment: I am a little confused. Can you tell me how to use the relative layout exactly? Also, how can I change the width of linear layout from the code?

Comment: I am still not able to get the layout as desired. Have updated the question with the code. please help.

Comment: RelativeLayout requires no orientation, remove it. Also add background="grey_color". All the rest looks fine. let me know if you still have problems.

Comment: its simply displaying the list items in a list. No background color anywhere!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3547/discussion-between-umang-and-superm)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use custom list adapter. This [tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html) will help you.